# Управление глагола-связки "быть"

Tags: управление

Вот пытаюсь разобраться, в какой же падеж ставить дополнение глагола "быть" как глагола-связки, если я его захочу явно употребить, или, может, это вообще часть составного глагола?

Во многих других славянских языках используется, например, творительный падеж.
Примеры:
польский - Jestem Polakiem (Я поляк, дословно (я есть) есмь поляком)
украинский - Я є українцем (Я есть украинцем, но: Я - українець)

Наоборот, в чешском, похоже, именительный:
jsem Čech (я - чех)

Так чем же все-таки являются слова после связки "быть" и в каком падеже их ставить?

Comment: ... я его захочу явно употребить... //// Употребите (для примера) в конкретной фразе, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском языке  немного **другая грамматика.**

Для примера. ***Он (есть) поляк. Он был  поляк.*** Он — подлежащее, поляк или был поляк — это составное именное сказуемое (связка *быть* + именная часть). В настоящем времени связка *есть* опускается.

Именная часть сказуемого выражена сущ. "поляк" **в форме И.п.**

Но в некоторых случаях используется Т.п., если нужно обозначить не постоянный, а **временный признак**, например: *он был тогда **учителем***. Но нельзя сказать: *он был поляком* (национальность — это всегда постоянный признак).

В то же время допускается форма: *Он был **учитель**.* В этом случае временной характер признака не подчеркивается, а условно считается постоянным.